# How to fix "This app contains a WatchKit app with an invalid bundle identifier"

Tags: ios, watchos, bundle-identifier

I'm trying to run the Apple sample project SimpleWatchConnectivity. I changed the bundle identifiers for all 3 parts to my company's domain (e.g. com.nemesys.simplewatchconnectivity). When I try to run on an iPhone and Apple Watch device, I get this error:

This app contains a WatchKit app with an invalid bundle identifier. The bundle identifier of a WatchKit app must have a prefix consisting of the companion app's bundle identifier, followed by a '.'.

If I add a dot (.) to the WatchKit app, then at build time, I get:

error: Embedded binary's bundle identifier is not prefixed with the parent app's bundle identifier.

I have tried a few solutions from answers to other related questions but none worked. Someone having a similar problem to archive and upload to the App Store approved an answer that basically said:

iOS app bundle identifier: com.nemesys.simplewatchconnectivity

WatchKit App bundle identifier: com.nemesys.simplewatchconnectivity.watchkitapp

WatchKit Extension bundle identifier: com.nemesys.simplewatchconnectivity.watchkitapp.watchkitextension

But when I tried those, I got the second error, the embedded binary's bundle identifier is not prefix with the parent app's bundle identifier.

Comment: Hi Nemesis, did you also check the info.plists and the build settings?

Comment: Yes, I did, double-checked everything. This is really stupid.

Answer (score 0):

After swapping the identifiers back in fort between the Bundle Identifier and the related identifiers, I got it to work. It's just like a cat and mouse game...